# Why is my External CSS is not being applied properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working with this code which is part of my  Web development course from udemy

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TinDog</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Limelight&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>




</head>


<body>

  <section id="title">

    <!-- Nav Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Tindog</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>


    <!-- Title -->

    <div class="row">
      <div class=" col-lg-6">


        <h1 >Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
        <button type="button">Download</button>
        <button type="button">Download</button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <!-- Features -->

  <section id="features">

    <h3>Easy to use.</h3>
    <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>

    <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
    <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>

    <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
    <p>Find the love of your dog's life or your money back.</p>

  </section>


  <!-- Testimonials -->

  <section id="testimonials">

    <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
    <img src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
    <em>Pebbles, New York</em>

     <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
    <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
    <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>

  </section>


  <!-- Press -->

  <section id="press">
    <img src="images/techcrunch.png" alt="tc-logo">
    <img src="images/tnw.png" alt="tnw-logo">
    <img src="images/bizinsider.png" alt="biz-insider-logo">
    <img src="images/mashable.png" alt="mashable-logo">

  </section>


  <!-- Pricing -->

  <section id="pricing">

    <h2>A Plan for Every Dog's Needs</h2>
    <p>Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>


    <h3>Chihuahua</h3>
    <h2>Free</h2>
    <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
    <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
    <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
    <button type="button">Sign Up</button>


    <h3>Labrador</h3>
    <h2>$49 / mo</h2>
    <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
    <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
    <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
    <button type="button">Sign Up</button>


    <h3>Mastiff</h3>
    <h2>$99 / mo</h2>
    <p>Pirority Listing</p>
    <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
    <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
    <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
    <button type="button">Sign Up</button>

  </section>


  <!-- Call to Action -->

  <section id="cta">

    <h3>Find the True Love of Your Dog's Life Today.</h3>
    <button type="button">Download</button>
    <button type="button">Download</button>

  </section>


  <!-- Footer -->

  <footer id="footer">

    <p>© Copyright 2018 TinDog</p>

  </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

which is linked to this css file ( i have not writen much in css file because i am unable to make any change)

```css
#title{ background-color:#ff4c68;}
h1{ line-height: 1.3;
font-size: 90px;
  background-color: yellow;  }
```

i noticed that  I was able to change background color but i  am unable to change line height, font size,font family of elements such as h1 ,h3 ,h2 etc from external css file but i can style it by inline css. why is that so?Please help.

Comment: `<h1 >Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>` Your starting `h1` tag has a gap in the brackets `<h1 >` should be `<h1>`

Comment: Move your css file after bootstrap css which probably has similar rules for h1. Last in takes precedence when rule specificity is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you load your stylesheet you are loading a third-party stylesheet from Bootstrap which probably applies its own styles to those elements.

Use the Inspector feature of your web browsers developer tools to look at your `h1` element and see which styles are applied to it, in which order, and where they come from.

Remember that styles are applied in [the cascade order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade#cascading_order) with rulesets of higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) overriding those of lower specificity and when specificity is equal *later* rulesets overriding earlier ones.

If specifity is equal then simply moving the `<link>` to your stylesheet so it is added **after** Bootstrap's will resolve your problem.